# Change webview URL in React native

Tags: react-native, webview

I have an app that has a WebView and a bottom navigation bar.

Back, forward and reload buttons work ok since there are goForward(), goBack() and reload() method.

But I also have a home button that should load the starting url.
I tried setting the new url with `this.setState` but it doesn't work.

```
this.setState({
  ...this.state,
  url: DEFAULT_URL,
})
```

Actually it works the first time. For example if I change the URL in the source and hot reload then it works. But if I click on any link home doesn't work anymore.

Is it possible to do this and if so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I solved it by appending timestamp to url because it seems setting a "new" url triggers the new render() or something.

So the function now goes like this:

```js
this.setState({ url: `${DEFAULT_URL}?t=${Date.now()}` })
```

Comment: This is absolutely stunning answer I ever saw on Stackoverflow. I like how you have worked..Thanks